# How does electric field intensity look like along a wire which has one end connected to an AC source and the other one is left free?

Tags: electricity, electric-fields

How does the electric field intensity look like along a wire with constant conductivity which has one end connected to an AC source and the other one is left free? I mean is the electric field the same at the beginning of the wire (close to the AC source terminal) and at the end of the wire? Or does the electric field intensity decrease along the wire due to some losses? In other words, which case from the ones depicted in the following picture is the correct one?

If the b) case is the correct one, what is the underlying principle causing the deacrease?

[image]

Comment: Why would there be an electric field perpendicular to the wire in the first place? Or am I misunderstanding the pictures?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, the AC source will alternately charge / discharge the conductor since there is an unavoidable capacitor formed by the conductor and, I presume, ground.

Comment: Martin, be aware that if the length of the conductor is *large enough*, the charge distribution will vary along the length of the conductor, i.e., the voltage and current along the conductor will be a function of position.  Essentially, you would have a 'long wire' antenna:  http://www.northcountryradio.com/Articles/Long%20Wire%20Antenna.htm

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is "It depends, and the way it's shown, it's neither!". The electric field around a wire depends very much on the electrostatic boundary conditions of the problem (you are showing a ground connection... what, exactly, is that connected to?) and on the frequency of the AC source relative to the resonance frequency of the antenna. Unless you specify the problem further, one can't give better answers. For one thing, there can be no cylindrical solution for a finite wire (the field will always assume a more spherical configuration around the end) and for the case of an infinite wire, there is no electrostatic solution for an AC signal, to begin with, since your antenna is always "long" and you are basically calculating the near and far field solutions of an infinitely long dipole. In either case there will be a field component parallel to the wire.